# PHP ajax database : how to pass two variables and get data of them in different div even one?

Tags: php, ajax

```
<script>
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

this script send one variable to php code and get data from database and put it in div tag,  how can we send two variables and get data in different tags.?

Answer (score 3):

to send 2 variables pass 2 parameters, like:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str+"&second_param="+some_other_value,true);
```

and in php

```
$query = $_GET['q'];
$new_str = $_GET['second_param'];
```

in simpler cases, you could do: in php

```
echo $first_data."{{}}".$second_data;
```

in js you can do:

```
var response_arr = xmlhttp.responseText;.split("{{}}"); //split by delimiter used in PHP
//and 
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = response_arr[0];
document.getElementById("txtHint_second").innerHTML = response_arr[1];
```

Comment: ok! . suppose i want to send one variable(pass one paramter) and get two fields from db in php and put two fields in two div tags even one .. how that ?

Comment: in that case you can just pass one parameter in your ajax .send(..) and respond 2 data from PHP side as in answer above..

Answer (score 0):

You have `xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);` in your code. You could pass your variables in that URL: `xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?var1=" + var1 + "&var2=" + var2, true);`

For the second part of your question, you can parse `xmlhttp.responseText`, get the desired data, and put it in your `div`s like `document.getElementById("your_div_id").innerHTML = [your_data]`.

I recommend you use XML or JSON when returning data, so it'll be easier to parse data and use it in your `div`s.

Comment: ok! . suppose i want to send one variable(pass one paramter) and get two fields from db in php and put two fields in two div tags even one .. how that ?

Comment: You can return a JSON from PHP holding the two fields. Then fetch the response, parse it as JSON, and simply take out your two fields and display them in a separate `div` as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Return

```
[ { "id" : "1", "name" : "test1" },
  { "id" : "2", "name" : "test2" },
  { "id" : "3", "name" : "test3" },
  { "id" : "4", "name" : "test4" },
  { "id" : "5", "name" : "test5" } ]
```

Javascript

```
// We'll pass this variable to the PHP function example_ajax_request
    var fruit = 'Banana';
    var fruit1 = 'Banana';

    // This does the ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {
            'action':'example_ajax_request',
            'fruit' : fruit,
            'fruit1' : fruit1
        },
        success:function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(id, item) {
                $("#dic"+id).html(data[id].item);
            });
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP Code and JSON :

```
$str = '{"div":{"id":"txtHint","innerHtml":"test test"},"span":{"id":"txtHint2","innerHtml":"safdsfsd"}}';
```

Javascript code

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {               
      alert(xmlhttp.responseText);  
    //document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        var json = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        alert(json);    
    }
  }
```

How to send multiple two variables :

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php?q="+str+"&p="+str2,true);
```