# PHP ajax database : how to pass two variables and get data of them in different options?

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

(Re Post) i had going through this tutarial : [PHP ajax database : how to pass two variables and get data of them in different div even one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956055/php-ajax-database-how-to-pass-two-variables-and-get-data-of-them-in-different) ,but it seems not working,and  i need to have 3 select works together.i choose first select option then using ajax to pass  data for getting second and using the

```
                function showUser(strOther);
```

to get third data which is related to the first and second answer.all is running well but the third select which is:

```
               <select id="txtHint1">
```

doesnt show me any answer.here is my scripts:

```
                <script>
                   function showForum(str) {
                     if (str=="") {
                   document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";


                         return;
                      } 
               if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
             // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
             } else { // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
             }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {

          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;


             }
               }

                xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
                }
                </script>

                <script>
                          function showUser(strOther) {
                 if(strOther==""){
             document.getElementById("txtHint1").innerHTML="";
                return;
                      }
                        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                          // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                       xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
               xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {

         document.getElementById("txtHint1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

              }
              }

               xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q1="+strOther,true);
              xmlhttp.send();
              }
            </script>
```

this is the select options which i get the ajax data:

```
                 <!-- this forum will be
                 choosed to pass data to get second 
                   select to filled up-->
                 <form>
                   <!-- first select-->
                  <select name="users" onchange="showForum(this.value)">
                 <option value="">All Orgs</option>
                 <option value="1">WebStatsProject</option>
                  <option value="2">mmu</option>

                  </select>
                  </form>
```

this select option will be filled by the first ajax request:
                         
                         
                         
                         All Forums
                         
                         
the third not show any data,the other two working properly:

```
                            <!-- third select-->
                             <select id="txtHint1">
                            <option value="All Users">All Users</option>
                            </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you not define `strOther`
try this

```
 function showUser(str,strOther){
```

and pass `strOther` to this function

Comment: tnx buddy,it s true,and its one of mistakes,but the other one is: i want it to get " q" first and " q1" after "q" had set,how about that?

Comment: because i have 3 select option and they are related,i mean the user should choose the first one,then the second one activated,then choose the second one to make the third one activated. and the third one have to have the first two answers to pass to sql like:  Organization -> Room -> officer (this is the flow)

Comment: i tried to make 2 script ,since i have to get the first one,and pass to the second one to get the third one,it is working but third one has no value,i guess because the " q" (the value of the first one) will be remove when for third iteration will go back to the .php file,how about that?

Comment: ,i had re post  it ,could you look at it?tnx